# Why does SQL Server conversion to bigint cause an error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I am trying to convert `varchar` to `bigint`:

```
select convert(bigint, (select(Replace((select value from sometable), ' ', ''))))
```

Why is it giving error???

> *Error converting data type varchar to bigint.*

thanks in advance

**Update**

This is part of query I am trying:

```
select top 1 * 
into #tblTemp 
from testTable 
where Status = 0 
order by Sno

declare @mobile varchar(50)

set @mobile = (select(Replace((select mobile from #tblTemp), ' ', '')))

--set @mobile = (select( Replace(' 9428017524', ' ', '')))

select convert(bigint, @mobile)

drop table #tblTemp
```

Comment: And what is the error did you got??

Comment: [**I think it is working fine.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7020)

Comment: It actually works for me, and I can't see an apparent problem. Is that your real query or have you just just pasted in what you expect the value from another query or variable to be?

Comment: Are you sure you have space before number and not some other symbol like tab, for example? for removing spaces you can use `ltrim` and `rtrim`, BTW

Comment: A typical error is when you have a `where` clause that "*should*" be filtering out all non-numeric values and such a conversion in the `select` clause. Unfortunately, SQL Server sometimes does the `SELECT` clause conversions before the filtering step takes place.

Comment: actully i am taking value from a temp table like this... select convert(bigint, (select( Replace((select mobile from #tblTemp), ' ', '')))). and this causes error. otherwise if i use static value as asked it shows correct answer. but actuly value from temp table is required

Comment: So, **you** need to take a bit of time and write an actual query that *demonstrates* the issue you're having - so that we can run it and see the problem. At the moment, all we can do is guess. Putting a query in your question that *doesn't* demonstrate the issue isn't going to help.

Comment: You've shown us a code fragment, but we're still not able to run it ourselves. If we make up sample data to put into the temp table, it's going to work fine.

Comment: :( still getting error.. dun know why replace function do not work..

Comment: It must work as long as `value` in number in range of `bigint` type. What value (as varchar) do you try to convert? Maybe it's not a number of `null`?

Comment: it has bigint value but a space at starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your real string is but for safety you can check `ISNUMERIC()` before convertion.

```
DECLARE @mobile varchar(50)
SELECT @mobile = REPLACE(mobile, ' ','') --much simplified version
FROM #tblTemp 

IF ISNUMERIC(@mobile)
   SELECT CONVERT(bigint, @mobile)
ELSE
   SELECT 0
```

Just by reading your queries, `you don't need a temp table` here at all. Everything can be done in a single query

```
SELECT TOP (1) CONVERT(bigint,  CASE ISNUMERIC( REPLACE(mobile,' ','') ) 
                                   WHEN 1 THEN REPLACE(mobile,' ','')
                                   ELSE 0 END )
FROM testTable 
WHERE Status = 0 
ORDER By Sno
```

Comment: Of course, `ISNUMERIC` will return 1 for `1d2` or `£`, because it answers a different question to the one you actually want to ask here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there are some more `'1E2'`. That is why I said `not sure what your real string is`. On the other hand it looks like a mobile number, so we can assume it is a number only field (may be + as well).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select convert(bigint, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@mobile + 'e0') = 0 
                THEN 0 ELSE @mobile)

 -- add this case statement to return only numeric values,     
 -- your query will fail for values like '123-415-6789', '(123)415-6789'
```

Check your mobile numbers data and see if there are any unexpected values in that column, you may have to replace `'-'` or `'('` or `')'` etc with `''`.

```
SeLECT * FROM #tblTmp
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Replace(mobile, ' ', '') + 'e0') = 0;
```

Comment: Of course, `ISNUMERIC` will return 1 for `1d2` or `£`, because it answers a different question to the one you actually want to ask here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, i updated my answer to test for numeric data correctly.